# Typescript: Disallow implicit reference to globals

Tags: typescript, lint, tslint

I have encountered this problem recently using TS, where one can accidentally access globals (e.g. window property).

Consider this example:

a.ts

```
// a.ts
export const postMessage  = (message: string) => console.log(message);
```

b.ts

```
// Forget to import, but use libs: dom... so it compliles perfectly
// import { postMessage } from './a';

postMessage('hello'); // Oooops
```

It seems, tslint can not and has no intention to handle this case. Saying, that TS handles it.
But may be TS does not...

IMO, desired behaviour would be to disallow implicit access to globals (global/window properties)

```
postMessage() // Error
window.postMessage() // OK
```

It think it is what eslint [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) rule does.

It seems there is an open issue in TS repo, but it is pretty stale ([Microsoft/TypeScript#14306](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14306))

If you know any recipe/info to fix this, plz share.
Or maybe i forget something and it is pretty easy to fix (hence, silly question)